# Save a LocalDate list to an array[][]

Tags: java, arrays, list

I would like to save the dates from the list to an array[][]?

My list is

```
List<LocalDate> dates = getWeekendDates
        (new LocalDate(year, month, (day+2)), new LocalDate((year+1), nymonth ,nyday));

private static List<LocalDate> getWeekendDates
    (LocalDate start, LocalDate end)
{
    List<LocalDate> result = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    for (LocalDate date = start;
         date.isBefore(end);
         date = date.plusDays(1))
    {
        int day = date.getDayOfWeek();
        // These could be passed in...
        if (day == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)
        {
            result.add(date);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I used :

```
String[] SundayArray = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);
System.out.println(SundayArray[5]);
```

This is the error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException 
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) 
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source) 
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

line 27 is `String[] SundayArray = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);`

Comment: A one-dimensional list cannot go into a two-dimensional array. What do you expect at [5][1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess your error comes on this line:

```
String[][] SundayArray = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);
```

You gave the method a one-dimensional array (`new String[dates.size()]`) and tried to make it a two-dimensional array (`String[][] SundayArray`).

You're also trying to implicitly convert a `List<LocalDate>` to a `String[]` which isn't possible. Your ArrayStoreException comes when you try to store the LocalDate in a String. You'll need something more like:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList(dates.size());
for (LocalDate date : dates) {
    temp.add(date.toString()); //toString() or the appropriate method
}
String[] SundayArray = temp.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);
```

Comment: Even if you put 
String[] SundayArray = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);
It gives me errors

Comment: This is the error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
 at Test.main(Test.java:27)

Comment: Thank you a lot! If i would like to put it to an array with two-dimensional in the first column;

Comment: If you wanted that, instead of `date.toString()`, you could do `new String[]{date.toString(), ""}` and make temp of type `List<String[]>`.